# Where is syslinux package for 20.10?

Tags: apt, package-management, syslinux, subiquity

I'm working with subiquity, Ubuntu Base, and PXE stuff. And for one of the steps I use `syslinux`. On 20.04.1 Live Server install, i just do early command

`apt-get install -y syslinux`

Which works.

But doing same on 20.10 installer crashes installer with message that package is missing.

I searched packages:
https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/syslinux

So it's there. And so is `syslinux-common`.

I ran command on server already installed with 20.10 - no error.

So why does subiquity complain?

I'll try to switch back to downloading syslinux release from `kernel.org` but I'd still like to know, as it's way easier to just pull a package from official repo (plus it seems it's newer build).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems that `syslinux` package isn't in initial `apt` cache at all in 20.10, so `apt` claims no package found.

All I needed to do was:

`apt-get update`

... And then run `apt-get install syslinux`

I had a script that jumps in and out of `chroot`, and I did one update inside `chroot`, but not in the `subiquity` installer shell itself...

Interesting enough, same exact workflow works in `subiquity` installer of 20.04.1 Live Server ISO image without any issues.

Comment: So that your answer is most helpful to future visitors who have your same problem, would you mind editing your answer and telling us exactly what to do?  This answer is unclear and I don't know how anyone would be able to follow along.

Comment: Ok, expanding it

Answer (score 0):

I was hitting a similar problem with ubuntu 22.04. I needed syslinux to prep some ISO images, but the only package available was `syslinux-common`, which didn't contain the actual syslinux binary.

After some searching, I discovered `syslinux` is still available in the Universe repositories.

I enabled the Universe repositories using `sudo add-apt-repository universe`. More details about adding the Universe repo at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository).